# Why is this logic to calculate the conditional probability for 3 different events wrong?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

lets say we have 3 events E, F, and G. now i want to calculate the probability :
P(G|E∩F)

so if i take E∩F = U

the required probability can be rewritten as :
P(G|U)

therefore the new formula should be:
P(G|U) = P(G∩U)/P(U)

which is the same as
$$\frac{P(G∩E∩F)}{P(E∩F)}$$

However it apparently is :
$$\frac{P(G∩E∩F)}{P(E).P(E∩F)}$$

My i know why it is so ?

Comment: Your logic is correct. Who told you otherwise?

Comment: To see that the "apparent" answer is wrong, consider the case $G=E=F.$ That answer reduces to $1/P(G)^2,$ which (unless $P(G)=1$) is an impossible probability.

Comment: @whuber wouldn't it reduce to $1/P(G)$?

Comment: @gunes Sorry; that was a typo.  The point remains valid.

Comment: @ArnoV are you sure it is right? cause my math textbook says that the Multiplication rule of probability for more than 2 events is:   
P(G∩E∩F) = P(E) P(F|E) P(G|(E∩F))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on one of your comments, the confusion is that from the (true) fact
\begin{align*}
P(G,E,F) =& P(E,F)P(G\mid E,F)\\
=& P(E)P(F\mid E) P(G\mid E,F)
\end{align*}

Where $A,B$ is shorthand for $A\cap B$. You somehow deduce that
$$ P(G\mid E,F) = \dfrac{P(G,E,F)}{P(E)P(E,F)}$$
Which is a mistake on your part, not the book. The correct deduction is
$$ P(G\mid E,F) = \dfrac{P(G,E,F)}{P(E)P(E\mid F)}$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, clearly I made a silly mistake :)